# Serialize function with PhantomJS bridge

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I have an array of links that use link parametr for function that scraped data by PhantomJS. 
How to serilize this function? This **for** statemant runs paralely 3 function in one time and i recive an **event error**.

In this case its proper to use **[async](https://npmjs.org/package/async)**, but how it use in series? Time of running the functions are always different, but how **async** should understood that it's done and start with new URL?

```
var phantom = require('phantom')
  , async = require('async');

var urls = [
  'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page',
  'http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Portada',
  'http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Hauptseite'
];

async.mapSeries(urls, getTitle, function(err, result){
    console.log(result);
})

function getTitle (link, callback) {
  phantom.create(function(ph) {
    return ph.createPage(function(page) {
      return page.open(link, function(status) {
        return page.evaluate((function() {
          return document.title;
        }), function(result) {
          callback(null, result);
          return ph.exit();
        });
      });
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Your `scrapedData` function doesn't look very asynchronous if it `return`s the results…

Comment: Why would the scrapings need to run in series? You could easily parallelize them.

Comment: @Bergi I added a **callbacks**, please check if they are in the correct place, 'cos it still donesn't work.

Comment: What is `scrapedData.bind(crapedData)`? Afaik it should be enough to pass the `crapedData` function only

Comment: @Bergi i just simplified the code to a minimum and it still doesn't working, I think thats a problem of **npm phantom**

Comment: Why? What happens, what exactly does not work? Does `getTitle` work on its own?

Comment: Btw, there are lots of better methods to get the article title from an URL - read about the [MediaWiki API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Api) :-)

Comment: @Bergi i just get wiki like example 'cos i can't nothing serialize by this way, but thanks for your time

Comment: @khaljava try creating 1 instance of phantomjs, and then open many pages. instead of `ph.exit()` do `page.close()` and exit only when all pages have called the callback.

Comment: @fusio it is an idea. I probably misunderstood the manual to the module - **ph.createPage()** and use it to create a lot of pages

Comment: no wait, I meant do `phantom.create` only once.. the error seems related to addresses already in use.. maybe you are trying to spawn another phantom instance on the same port?

Comment: @fusio can you write in answer the code how to run only **page.open**, to do not create another phantom instance. And I do not quite understand ports - its better to start phantom with parameters and set another port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try something like:

```
var links = []
var _ph

function init(cb) {
    phantom.create(function(ph) {
        //for each link in links call doStuff()
        _ph = ph 
        doStuff(ph, link, cb)   
    })   
}

function doStuff(ph, link, cb) {
    ph.createPage(function(page) { //does things in parallel?
      page.open(link, function(status) {
        page.evaluate((function() {
          document.title;
        }), function(result) {
          cb(null, result);
          page.close();
        });
    });
}

var counter = links.length
var titles;

function results(err, res) {
  titles.push(res)

  if(--counter == 0) {
    //done
    _ph.exit()
  }
 }

init(results)
```

Probably not working code (I wrote it here), but I hope you get the idea. If you want to only use 1 page, something like:

```
var links = []
var _ph
var _page

function init(cb) {
    phantom.create(function(ph) {

        _ph = ph 
        ph.createPage(function(page) {
             _page = page
             doStuff(link, cb)
        }   
    })   
}

function doStuff(page, link, cb) {
      page.open(link, function(status) {
        page.evaluate((function() {
          document.title;
        }), function(result) {
          cb(null, result);
          page.close();
        });
    });
}

 var counter = links.length
var titles;

function results(err, res) {
  titles.push(res)

  if(--counter == 0) {
    //done
    _ph.exit()
    return
  }

  doStuff(links[counter], results)
 }

init(results)
```

Comment: Good idea, but you really should use the `async` library when it's already available :-)

Comment: @fusio thank for answer, but for what you have created **'_ph'** variable